# Pseudo-element not being treated as separate flex item

Tags: css, flexbox, pseudo-element

I've read that pseudo-elements:

a) aren't clickable when attached to links

b) are treated as unique items in a flex container

But this pseudo-element I've attached to a link is:

a) clickable

b) not being treated as a separate flex item

What am I missing?

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);

body { 
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: thistle;
  font-family: Raleway;
  text-align: center;
}

nav{
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

a:nth-child(3):after{
      display: block;      
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;      
      background: url(https://i.imgur.com/qRtsMi0.png);
      background-size: cover;
      content: "";      
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">ONE</a>
  <a href="#">TWO</a>
  <a href="#">THREE</a>
  <a href="#">FOUR</a>
  <a href="#">FIVE</a>
  <a href="#">SIX</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: clickable?? only the `cursor` is `pointer` (because the parent is `a`)but you can NOT attach a function only to pseudo  when click (like `$('a:nth-child(3):after').click(...)`)

Comment: a) You read wrong. A pseudo element inserted into a link becomes part of that link, and as such can also be clicked to activate the link. b) You have inserted a pseudo child element into your _link_ here, not into your nav element. It would have to be a pseudo child of the latter here, because _that_ is the flex container. (If you had `<a><span></span></a>` instead of a pseudo element, that would not make that `span` a flex item on the same level as the existing links either now would it?)

Comment: What you've read is incorrect. And your pseudo-elements aren't in the flex container.

Comment: Thanks. It was a semantic misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

a) pseudo elements attached to links are indeed part of the link. they aren't "clickable" in the sense that they can't be targeted separately with `onClick`.

b) pseudo elements **attached to** flex containers are treated as items. Pseudo elements **attached to items** in flex containers are not.